# Is it theroretically possible to replace all mutexes with futures?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, promise, mutex, future

For instance: How would a programmer design a system that requires many threads to read and write concurrently to shared data using the future-promise paradigm *without* using mutexes or other locking mechanisms?

If there is an answer to this problem, are there other situations that provably require mutual exclusion?

Comment: Any future or similar high-level construct is almost certainly implemented with mutex(es) or other locking mechanisms inside.  If "lock free" were actually so great, mutexes and other locking mechanisms would not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Any high-level concurrent API (async/await, future-promise, callbacks, ...) needs a way to run concurrently on some system and they all use low-level primitives such as locks and atomics.

The future-promise concurrency API requires the existence of an event-loop that schedule concurrent work and await not finished work, so it needs a way to block the execution at some point.

An application that reads and writes concurrently to and from many threads (multiple consumers multiples producers pattern) would a concurrency API feature such as a channel or a concurrent queue.